# html - best practice, max-width of canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas

What is the largest width/height that could be applied to the canvas element effectively? (only draw to the canvas once), also think of mobile etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking of mobile and wanting the largest possible, those are working at contrary aims.

Mobile the largest reasonable depends on the device size for viewing. Your question sounds more like it is asking what is the largest canvas you can draw...which would depend on what you are putting on it and the hardware of the computer it is being rendered on.

There is not alot/any reasons to use super giant canvases, as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, I'm working on a campaign where a bigger canvas would really ease things up. How terrible would it theoretically be to have a canvas, say, 1500x50 on a iPhone4s/newer android?

Comment: It would be very hard for the user to use in some orientations. Either their phone would zoom out to try and show it all or they woudl have to pinch zoom all the time...

Comment: I'm going to move it left/right. The user will be able to see it all

Comment: Maybe that would work, and I don't think 1500px wide is even close to approaching the max rendering size of a canvas, though some of that will depend on how much you are rendering to it...